# Connect to the Azure Databricks via odbc using python and Azure AD

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, odbc, databricks, simba

Could you please give me some instructions or resources (as I am not able to find anything that could potentially point me to the right direction) with information of how to connect to the Azure Databricks using odbc (python simba driver) and Azure AD service principal credentials?

I've already tried to use that kind of connection:

```
driver = os.getenv("SIMBA_DRIVER", "path to libsparkodbc_sb64.so")

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource, cliend_id, client_secret)

odbc_conn_str = f"Driver={driver};Host=urlfordatabricks;PORT=443;HTTPPath=sqlpathforcluster;AuthMech=11;Auth_Flow=0;Auth_AccessToken={token.get('accessToken');SSL=1;"

with pyodbc.connect(odbc_conn_str, autocommit=True) as conn:
    logic...
```

Unfortunately, I'm receiving following error: [Simba][DSI] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the error message for key `DSCurlRecvError'`.

I can connect to the databricks platform using my own personal token and AuthMech=3 with UID and PWD but it is not what is desirable.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: That error means that the key being looked for could not be found. Have you tried  [Get an Azure Active Directory token using a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/service-prin-aad-token#--use-the-service-principals-azure-ad-access-token-to-access-the-databricks-rest-api) and [Connect pyodbc to Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/pyodbc) - here  Replace  `<personal-access-token>`  with the value of your Azure AD access token for your Azure Databricks workspace.